# How to run a shell script using Spotlight passing a parameter?

Tags: macos, shell, spotlight

It was mentioned that we can execute a shell script using spotlight renaming it as "myscript.command" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877741/how-to-run-a-shell-script-using-spotlight). But is it possible to pass a parameter to the script when calling it from Spotlight?

For example:

Script `myscript.command`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Parameter: $1"
```

On Spotlight:

```
myscript.command test
```

Output:

```
(...)
Parameter: test
(...)
[Process completed]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that spotlight supports this. But you can write your shell script in such a way that it asks the user for input, using read or something like applescript.

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/690141/run-a-shell-script-from-spotlight

Comment: @mac13k That shows how to run a script from Spotlight without passing any parameters; but the OP already knows how to do that.

Comment: It doesn't seem easily doable with a simple script, although you might be interested in the [Flashlight project](https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight/), but one big downside is that it requires SIP to be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not seem to be possible currently.